# Seg fault when assigning a dynamically allocated 2D array to a double pointer within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, segmentation-fault

I am creating a game with a 2d array as the board. Originally, I tried to dynamically allocate the board to the struct in one function, but figured I would create the board, and then assign this newly created board to the double point within the struct.

This is my declaration of the struct. When I run my create board function, everything works out, but when I print to it there is a seg fault, so I am going to assume I haven't allocated enough space and there is an issue with my pointers.

```
typedef struct Game_State{
    int num_rows;
    int num_cols;
    int num_mines;
    char** board;
    char MINE;
    char hidden_tile;
    char marked_tile;
    char flagged_tile;
    char revealed_tile;
}game;
```

This is the code I used to create a dynamically allocated board depending on the command line arguments of rows and columns, yet when I print the board, there is a segmentation fault!

```
void create_board(struct Game_State game){
    //intitialization
    int i;
    int j;
    int num_rows = game.num_rows;
    int num_cols = game.num_cols;
    char  hidden_tile = game.hidden_tile;
    char** board; 
    printf("Create Board Rows: %d\n", num_rows);
    printf("Create Board Cols: %d\n", num_cols);
    printf("Create Board Hidden Tile: %c\n", hidden_tile);
    //dynamically allocates space for the board (2x2)
    board =(char**) malloc(num_rows *sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i){//for each row
        board[i] = (char*) malloc(num_cols * sizeof(char));
        for(j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j){
            board[i][j] = hidden_tile;
        }
    }
    game.board=board;
}
```

***UPDATE***

I believe our segmentation fault is coming from our printboard function, we try to print the board with headers. I used this exact code for another function with success, so I think maybe I'm accessing my board wrong?

```
void print_board(struct Game_State game){//defines print board function
    //intitializations
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int num_row_val = game.num_rows;
    int l = num_row_val;
    int num_col_val = game.num_cols;
    char** board =game.board

    printf("%d\n", num_row_val);
    printf("%d\n", num_col_val);
    printf("%d\n", l);

    while(l > 0){
        for(i = 0; i < num_row_val; ++i){
            printf("%d " , (l - 1));//prints row headers
            for(j = 0; j < num_col_val; ++j){//prints board
                printf("%c ",game.board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            --l;
        }
    }
    for(k = 0; k < num_col_val; ++k){//prints column header
        printf(" %d" , k);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you're doing the pointer assignment the wrong way. Should be `char **board = malloc(num_rows *sizeof(char*));` then `game.board = board;`.

Comment: I have tried this, still with a seg fault. This issue might not be in this particular program, but in the function where I am printing the board.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a `struct Game_State` to a function, you are passing a *copy* of the variable. More specifically, the `.board` member of the `game` variable inside `create_board()` is a copy of the `.board` member of the variable that was passed to the function.

So when you return from the `create_board()` function, the `game` variable ceases to exist and the only pointer you had to the allocated memory is irretrievably lost. The `.board` member of the variable that was passed *to* the function remains uninitialized and, unsurprisingly, your program crashes inside `print_board()`.

Whenever you need to modify a `Game_State` structure inside a function, you will need to pass a *pointer to* `struct Game_State`:

```
void create_board (struct Game_State *game) {  /* Pointer to Game_State */
  ...
}

int main (void) {
    struct Game_State g;

    create_board (&g);  /* Address of g. */
    ...
}
```

You will also have to access the struct members inside `create_board()` differently. These lines:

> ```
> int num_rows = game.num_rows;
> int num_cols = game.num_cols;
> char  hidden_tile = game.hidden_tile;
> ...
> game.board=board;
> ```

should be changed to:

```
int num_rows = game->num_rows;
int num_cols = game->num_cols;
char  hidden_tile = game->hidden_tile;
...
game->board=board;
```

which is shorthand for:

```
int num_rows = (*game).num_rows;
int num_cols = (*game).num_cols;
char  hidden_tile = (*game).hidden_tile;
...
(*game).board=board;
```